# how to use dynamic assertion method name?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Let's say I have this in a test:

```js
await t.expect(Selector('input')).ok()
```

And I would like to have (something like) this:

```js
let func = 'ok';
await t.expect(Selector('input'))[func]()
```

This is so that I can have a map from selector to function, in order to iterate
over it and check whether some elements are in the page (`ok`) and some not (`notOk`).

My above attempt does not work and returns with an interesting error:

```
  code: 'E1035',
  data: [
    'SyntaxError: test.js: await is a reserved word (325:14)'
  ]
```

I believe this is because Testcafe is doing some magic under the hood.

What would be the correct syntax to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you skipped the Selector property that you want to check (e.g. `exists`, `visible`, `textContent`, etc.). The following test example works properly with TestCafe v1.14.2:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture`A set of examples that illustrate how to use TestCafe API`
    .page`http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/`;


const developerName = Selector('#developer-name');
const submitButton = Selector('#submit-button');

test('New Test', async t => {
    await t
        .typeText(developerName, 'Peter Parker')
        .click(submitButton);

    let assertFunc = 'ok';
    await t.expect(Selector('#article-header').exists)[assertFunc]();
});
```